# Cakephp2 Baking

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i am using Cakephp2 and i am trying to baking my application using commandprompt

here is my steps

```
c:/>xampp\htdocs\projectname\app>..\cake\console\cake bake
```

it doesnot work .

But if i use cakephp1.3 with same steps it works fine and look like as

```
Interactive Bake Shell
[D]atebase Configuration 
[M]odel 
so on
```

AnyBody Tell me what to do ?

Thanks

Comment: @deceze: the system can't find the path specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of the Cake console has changed in 2.0. It's in: `YOUR_CAKE_DIR/lib/Cake/Console/`. Change YOUR_CAKE_DIR to the path to your Cake installation and you should be able to invoke `cake bake` again.

Just realised you're developing on Windows, I guess, in that case, the path becomes:

```
c:/>xampp\htdocs\projectname\app>..\lib\Cake\Console\cake bake
```

Comment: Note to OP -you may need to add the environment variable again; and I read about renaming the `.bat` file to prevent it clashing with the a `1.3` install - can't find the resource but something to consider.

Comment: @Ross: no we don't need to add environment variable again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without changing your path variables. 
For window machine and xampp you can do following step to bake:-

1. Type cd\ press enter
2. Type cd:/xampp/php press enter
3. Type php.exe C:/xampp/htdocs/projectName/lib/cake/console/cake.php bake   press enter